# Matlab noise source discontinuity

Tags: matlab, filtering, gnuradio

Using Matlab, I've made some random noise, filtered it and then successfully saved it as a gnuradio readable file for a file source. Once used in gnuradio, I set the file source to repeat and then viewed it using QT Gui Frequency Sink. I can see the filtered noise fine, but every now and then (every 10 seconds or so), the spectrum will drop in power and jump around for around a tenth of a second, then return back to normal power. My sample rate for the matlab filter is 320k and same with my gnuradio sample rate if that matters.

I think it may have to do with the fact that the noise generated on matlab is going to be a sequence that is repeated on gnuradio. I think the discontinuity happens right when the sequence repeats. Any idea how I can stop this discontinuity so I can transmit without having to worry about it? If I'm missing any info, please let me know and I'll edit the question. Thanks in advance.

[image: Matlab SPTool parameters used to create the filtered noise]

[image: GNU Radio Flow Chart]

[image: QT GUI Frequency Sink Output]

NOTE: I needed to create a matlab binary file to be able to read it on GNU Radio. GNU Radio reads the binary file from my desktop, then uses the information as the file source.

Comment: Maybe you can post your code or at least the relevant parts? It's hard to imagine what you're doing.

Comment: Well the filtered noise was created using SPTool on Matlab. You just put in the parameters and you can create the filtered noise easily. I'll post a picture of that. As for the GNU Radio part, I will post the flow graph as well. There is no code that I have created, only generated code from these two tools. I have also added a picture of the frequency sink display without the discontinuity.

Comment: UPDATE: I've realized the discontinuities aren't due to some repeat. They are pretty random. I recorded the time between each discontinuity and it is definitely random. I still don't know what is causing them though.

Comment: I can't find it either, sorry.